# mandatory try/except on .get() query and "referenced before assignment" error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

i've been trying to run a query which doesnt return any result (and it's ok)

```
user_meta = meta.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
```

and i was getting an error

```
meta matching query does not exist
```

which is wierd ! i've expected to get and empty set or false in return instead of this giant error !

anyway i've tried to run query in a try/except  block as it was suggested here

```
def get(request):
    try :
     user_meta = meta.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    except user_meta.DoesNotExist :
     user_meta = None

    user_gates = gates.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id )
    return HttpResponse("this is a response" )
```

now i get

```
local variable 'user_meta' referenced before assignment
```

except it's not !! unless django talks about this line

```
except user_meta.DoesNotExist :
```

honestly it would be ridicules if i have to define variable before try/except block (not to mention i think having to put a query in try/except is too much in the first place )

so whats wrong with my code ?
and do i have to put every single .get() query in try/except block?

**btw  i know about `get_object_or_404` and i dont want to rise 404 error if not match any ... or use .filter() + loop**

Comment: Please don't change your question after people have already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `meta` is the name of your model (though classes are usually capitalised), you want to catch `except meta.DoesNotExist:`

Comment: thanx , so do i have to use try/except on every query ?

Comment: well that depends. there are several ways to query, including `filter` that you mention above. `.get()` assumes exactly one match and throws exceptions for 0 or >1 matches. depends on your exact use-case

Comment: like in my case there is a one t one relation between 2 tables , so basically i have to choose between .filter()+loop or try/except .. thanx